# Android lifecycle - where do I check whether query returned no items?

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

EDIT: I've removed code that wasn't relevant.

I'm writing an app in Android studio, and connecting it to Firebase for authentication and database. I've been following their examples, and this has led to me using fragments for the first time. I'm not totally sure what I'm doing.

What I want is this: when the User has been authenticated and is directed to the MainActivity (their Home screen, basically), the list of items (called charts) they have created is retrieved and displayed. (In the future there will also be a list of library items they have liked, but that's not implemented yet.  However, I've set up a pager/tabs system so that I can slot it in at a later stage.) This works ok, using a Recycler View to show all the retrieved items.  However, if the user has no items, I want to display a special message instead, along with a button to create their first item.  I'm just not sure at which point in the activity/fragment lifestyle I do this, and how.

I think the relevant code is as follows (I can post more if needed, but I think this is it):

In MainActivity, in OnCreate (the user is creating Charts):

```
mPagerAdapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
    private final Fragment[] mFragments = new Fragment[] {
            new MyChartsFragment()
    };
    private final String[] mFragmentNames = new String[] {
            getString(R.string.heading_my_charts)
    };
};
```

So that shows the tab ("My Charts"), and the corresponding list.

MyChartsFragment is an extension of ChartListFragment, just with a specific query. ChartListFragment contains:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_charts, container, false);

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    mRecycler = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.charts_list);
    mRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mEmptyListView = mRootView.findViewById(R.id.empty_chart_list);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Set up Layout Manager, reverse layout
    mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    mManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    mRecycler.setLayoutManager(mManager);

    // Set up FirebaseRecyclerAdapter with the Query
    Query chartsQuery = getQuery(mDatabase);
    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Chart, ChartViewHolder>(Chart.class, R.layout.item_chart,
            ChartViewHolder.class, chartsQuery) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final ChartViewHolder viewHolder, final Chart model, final int position) {
            final DatabaseReference chartRef = getRef(position);

            // If list is empty, show the message instead
            // Currently this doesn't work - nothing appears
            mEmptyListView.setVisibility(mAdapter.getItemCount() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        // Show message if the list is empty
        // Currently not working
        @Override
        protected void onDataChanged() {
            mEmptyListView.setVisibility(mAdapter.getItemCount() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    };
    mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

This uses the following layout:

fragment_all_charts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/charts_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_chart" />

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/empty_chart_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Testing"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

So, this is all fine if charts exist, but if not, then I'd like the whole "My Charts" page to be replaced by a message saying something like "Get started by creating your first chart", with a button or something to click. My question is, how do I get it to test for the number of charts, and if it's 0, to replace the MyChartsFragment with another layout with the message and button?

Comment: in your `RecyclerAdapter` check for `getItemCount()==0` and show your "no items for you" view then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From FirebaseUI 1.1 onwards there is an `onDataChanged()` method in the adapters you can override and then check the item count as Shark commented.

From the [samples app of FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/1.1.0/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/uidemo/database/ChatActivity.java#L163):

```
    @Override
    protected void onDataChanged() {
        // if there are no chat messages, show a view that invites the user to add a message
        mEmptyListView.setVisibility(mRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I was using too low a version of Firebase UI, for a start. However, I've now started using what I need, and still nothing is showing up when the data set is empty. I'd appreciate any further ideas!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a very inefficient tool for interactively debugging your code, so I recommend you run you run the app in a debugger. Does your `onDataChanged()` get called? What's the value of `mAdapter.getItemCount()` when that happens?

Comment: Thanks, Frank, you're right.  I'm going to re-think my approach here - think I'll remove the fragment pager for now, and try to add the chart list directly rather than via a fragment, and then work on pulling the fragment out once I have it up and running. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I donot know how this works with fetching data from firebase, but i assume it works similar to fetching data from a contentprovider:

- you define a query
- add the query to an adapter
- attach the adapter to a view
- the view calls registerContentObserver to get informed when data has changed or when fetching data has finished.

If your app wants to be notified that an image in the android media database has changed you can use

```
activity.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, true, new ContentObserver(null) {
    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        // something in MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI has changed
    }
});
```

If your app wants to inform all registered ContentObserver-s it will call

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```